# How specify the location of TAGS file?

Tags: ctags, exuberant-ctags

I have the following parameters for the `ctags`:

```
ctags -f TAGS -e -R --langmap=php:+.inc.foo.bar --list-maps=php
```

Any idea how I could specify where the TAGS-file should be placed? I found nothing about this in `man ctags` and `ctags --help`, only about which filename the TAGS file should have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file name after parameter `-f` can be just a file name without path, but can be also with a relative path or with an absolute path.

A Windows example:

```
ctags -f "C:\My Projects\ProjectX\ProjectX_tags.txt" -e -R --langmap=php:+.inc.foo.bar --list-maps=php
```

Double quotes are needed only if the path or file name contains a space or one of these characters `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ ``. The usage of surrounding `"` is never wrong. It can be just wrong not using surrounding `"` on Windows around a file name argument string depending on the characters.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Didn't expected to get any answer one month later.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
ctags -f - > /path/to/final/dest/tags
```

so the `-f -` part redirects the tags file to stdout, then we use shell redirection to send it to the destination of our choice.